# How to get jenkins job description using shell

Tags: jenkins

I wanted to take the description given for each job in jenkins. Is there any way of getting it by shell script?

Comment: Jenkins has a [CLI](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/#common-commands) or an [API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) that you could use.

Answer (score 2):

Access your jenkins master node:

```
ssh <jenkins_user>@<jenkins_master_node>
```

Locate then go to `jobs` directory:

```
cd /jenkins/jobs/
```

Then do this:

```
find . -type f -iname config.xml | xargs grep -m1 "description"
```

Basically every Jenkins job you create has a respective config.xml on your master with all the information you entered in the Jenkins UI. One of the entries in this config.xml is a `description` tag that you write when making a job. I have limited the output to only show the first `description` in the config.xml files. You can remove the `-m1` to see all the descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Use Groovy from the script console.

```
items = Jenkins.instance.allItems.findAll {
   // Gets all jobs in the portfolio
   it instanceof hudson.model.FreeStyleProject
}

items.each {
  println it.fullName + " : " + it.description
}
return
```